# Artifactory plugin for Jenkins Pipeline saving files in Artifactory like folder structure

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

The question is if this is the expected behavior when downloading an artifact, given that:

`pattern: "Repository/Modules/SoftwareName/Number/file.zip"
 target: "folderInWorkspace/"`

Result the file is downloaded in: 
`folderInWorkspace/Repository/Modules/SoftwareName/Number/file.zip`

Expected result:
`folderInWorkspace/file.zip`

If that is the expected behavior can this be changed to the desired behavior?

I tried specifing the file in target like:
`target: "folderinWorkspace/file.zip"`
but this gives the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed the expected behavior.

Jenkins Artifactory plugin preserves by default the directory structure in Artifactory.

In order to change that behavior, add `flat: "true"` to the file spec:

```
  "pattern": "Repository/Modules/SoftwareName/Number/file.zip",
  "target": "folderInWorkspace/",
  "flat": "true"
```

For more information see: [Download spec schema](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+File+Specs#UsingFileSpecs-DownloadSpecSchema).